# Android Battery Stats in Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, fragment, battery

All tutorials on the subject seem to assume you are using a basic activity to retrieve battery information. I am trying to get the information from a fragment activity. I've worked out that this is how to get the things I am looking for in a single activity.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private TextView batteryTxt;
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
  int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
  batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
}
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
super.onCreate(b);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}
}
```

However, I am unable to figure out what changes are needed for it to fit into the fragment activity as it appears to be a slightly different process.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Move `mBatInfoReceiver` in `HomeFragment` and call `registerReceiver` in `onCreateView` .

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView batteryTxt;
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
  int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
  batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
}
};

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    batteryTxt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: In the first example I am getting the battery percentage and displaying it in the TextView. `batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");`  so it might say 25%. I want to be able to do this from a fragment activity. I don't know how the code (from example 1) fits into the second example to produce the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the help. it got me on the road to finding a solution but I needed a fair more bit of added code to achieve what I wanted (in the post below)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a basic working example with this.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView batteryTxt;
int health = 0;


public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    batteryTxt=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    setare();

}

public void setare(){

    batteryTxt.setText("Health: " + health + "%");



}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        health= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);


    }
};

}
```